# Simple endpoint to send the first message to NServiceBus

Tags: asp.net-web-api, nservicebus, nancy, owin

I want to create a simple endpoint where I can receive some string and then parse and create a message for the nservicebus. I already tried asp.net webapi, nancy and owin.

In asp.net web.api on my RegisterServices method from ninject I configured nservicebus with this

```
Configure.Serialization.Xml();
Configure.Transactions.Disable();
Configure.With()
    .NinjectBuilder(kernel)
    .UseTransport<Msmq>()
    .UnicastBus()
    .SendOnly();
```

I can send one message from my controller when the server starts, but when I try to send another one it throws this exception:

```
Error loading Ninject component ICache
No such component has been registered in the kernel's component container.`
```

With nancy or owin I implement the interface IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops and in the Start method I create a self hosted instance of nancy or owin. It´s run smoothly and i can access from my browser the endpoints. The problem is to inject the IBus property in nancy module or owin startup class, the IBus property is always null

Any thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: Have you defined the InjectAttribute on the IBus property?

Comment: No, I'll try this. Another doubt, the nservicebus looks for classes that implements some know interfaces to do the injection?